# Filters in ListView

Tags: wpf

I am creating an application which populate rows from the database with filter option. Please sugest me how to add a filter button in ListViewColumns?

Thanks for your reply.

Regards,
Prabu

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ICollectionView interface, you can check out this article: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/